# Which strategy to use? Object Clone or a simple Map

Tags: java

I need help with something. my code is of the following template.
Assume customObject has multiple property1, property2, ..property100.

```
List<CustomObject> customObjectList = /*<method call to external API that returns the said list >*/
if(customObjectList != null && customObjectList.size() > 0){
    //*** point A ***<clone the Object>
    resultList = <some method that process the above list>(customObjectList)

    if(resultList.size() > 0){
        for(Iterator<Map.Entry<CustomObject, ExternalResponse>> itr = resultList.entrySet().iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
            //code that modifies the properties in the CustomObjects
            //*** point B ***resetAProperty(<Object clone>)
        }
    }
}
```

At point B, I need the one unmodified specific property of original object to use in the method. I have two strategies for this:

1. Clone the object at point A, and use the cloned copy to get the
   property as shown in above code. At point A, Use a for loop and a
2. Map to form an associate array of object names, property original
   values and traverse them to get the property initial value at point
   B

Comment: clone should only be done if you want a second object of the same class whit a little to none difference.
If you want one property unchanged, you could simple store it in a temporary variable or make sure it won't be changed by 'the code that modifies the properties in the CustomObjects'

Comment: That's what i mean in strategy 2, create a map of object names to property values (since it's a list of objects). But then, i had to loop through the objectlist at point A (to set the property) and point B to get my property value which felt a bit messy. So wondering if there's a better method?

Comment: I seem to recall the general consensus on cloning is that the whole concept is hopelessly broken and you should use copy constructors.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without modifying the original class (a third party one).

Comment: You would still have to `deep clone` the values, because just copying a reference is just that a reference to the object. You have to create a new instance of the object, `java.lang.String` is `Immutable` and the way you `clone` it is to do `new String(oldString);`.

Comment: So cloning is totally a bad idea? in which cases (a complex one like this i mean) is it considered a better solution?

Comment: Depends on why you would need to deep-clone a third-party class. I'd consider just not clobbering it in the "method that processes it". Or only exposing an immutable wrapper around it.

Comment: Upon rereading your code, my fix would be to save the one property you need *before* modifying the objects, and storing it in say an `IdentityHashMap` so you can then get the original value later. It would help if your code had a dummy implementation of `CustomObject` and some sample data and actual changes to them instead of prose descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Avoid Cloning because it always requires Deep Cloning

`.clone()` especially on a `List` will almost always end in tears because you would have to `deep clone` all the objects in the list, all their referenced objects, and so on.

`Deep Cloning` means you have to make a binary copy of every last object in the Object graph. Just copying a `reference` will give you a `shallow copy` and you will see any changes that are made to the `referenced` object. Just miss one property and you will have a hell of a time finding that bug.

#### Solution

What you should do is make all your `CustomObject` instances `Immutable` and then you don't need to worry about versioning, they can never change, mutation would involve creating a new instance that is also `Immutable` and a complete different object. Then you never had to worry about versions.

Of course all the instance variables that point to other objects will need to be `Immutable` as well. This is the same problem as the `deep clone` but taking from another angle. A much more manageable angle.

Comment: I've had to mess with object cloning in the past and ran into deep cloning issues. The way to clean up the code and keep it simple was using the Immutable approach as described above. This approach keeps the code readable and also clarifies your intentions to everybody who reads your code later.

Comment: The object is pretty big. Does making it immutable considered proper programming practice? All i need is one single property from a lot and it feels like cloning and functional approach introduce a new level of undesired complexity just for the sake of one simple value i need at point B

Comment: Google the two techniques, and see which one is considered a nightmare of complexity and source of never ending bugs. Just Google for `Java Deep Clone` and the like. Functional programming uses `Immutable` objects by default. Just look at `Erlang`, no mutable objects and it works great!

Comment: yes i figured immutable object is better than deep cloning, but it seems a bit much to refactor the whole application just for a minor fix.

Comment: @BobLoblaw The point is your proposed fix is not a minor change. You'd need a whole mess of reflection code to deeply clone an object graph correctly unless the whole object graph is `Serializable` and even then you're not sure if you're not doing something ridiculous. (Like if the object graphs includes some objects it's not a good idea to clone, like database collections.)

Comment: exactly, and you have to deal with the possibility of circular references which when deep cloning will result in stackoverflows! Even if every object is `Serializable` it doesn't give you anything for `clone` it is just a `Marker` interface, it has no implementation.